# Predicting Accuracy of the svm classifier

Tags: python

I am trying to predict labels for text documents. I have applied linear svm classifier and got the predicted labels for each document but when i am trying to find the accuracy of the classifier I am getting a strange error.My code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC  

clf = LinearSVC()
model = clf.fit_transform(train_temp,train_tags) 
pred = clf.predict(test_temp)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

y_test = np.array(test['Tags'])
print accuracy_score(pred, y_test)
```

When I execute the above code I get the following error:

raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
ValueError: unknown is not supported

Any solution to such error?

Comment: please provide the sample of `train_tmp`, `train_tags`, `test_temp`, and `test`

Comment: Can you insert `print pred` and `print y_test` just before the last line and copy&paste their outputs to hint us?